# Finding min and max in 2-D arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, minmax

After running this code , it will generate a random array of desired rows and columns . Then a loop will divide the array by its diagonal into an upper side and lower side.In the upper side the loop will look for a `max number` and in the lower side the loop will look for a `min number` . Then in the final stage I need to change the positions of `min` and `max` . `Max` in place of `min` and vice versa.The code runs and finds the `min` and `max`.Don't know how to change their places.

> Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){
int rows, columns;
int max = INT_MAX;
int min = INT_MIN;
int XindexOfMax, YindexOfMax;
int XindexOfMin, YindexOfMin;

cout << "Enter rows: ";
cin >> rows;
cout << "Enter columns: ";
cin >> columns;

int **array = new int *[rows];            //generating random array
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    array[i] = new int[columns];

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));         //generating randoms

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){           //loop for the main array
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        array[i][j] = rand() % 10;    
        cout << array[i][j] << " "; 
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

cout << "For finding Max: " << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){             //upper half of the diagonal
    for(int j = 0; j < columns - i; j++){
        cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        if(array[i][j] > max){
            max = array[i][j];
            XindexOfMax = i;              //find x and y coordinates if max
            YindexOfMax = j;
        }

    }
    cout << "\n";
}
cout << "For finding Min: " << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){          // lower half of the diagonal
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        if (j < columns - i - 1){
            cout << "  ";
        }
        else{
            cout << array[i][j] << " "; 
            if(array[i][j] < min){
                min = array[i][j];
                XindexOfMin = i;       //find x and y coordinates if min
                YindexOfMin = j;
            }
        }
    }
cout << "\n";
}
cout << "Result" << endl;
//swapping positions of min and max 
std::swap(array[XindexOfMax][YindexOfMax], array[XindexOfMin][YindexOfMin]);

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){        
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        cout << array[i][j] << " ";   //Printing the final array
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Comment: Note that what you have there is **not** a 2D array of integers. It is a 1D array of pointers, each pointer pointing to an 1D array of integers. `int (*array)[columns]` would be a 2D array.

Comment: Can you edit the section to see how it works? @spectras

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `min` and `max` values, you need to remember the indizes where you found `min` and `max`, respectively. Then you can exchange the values (either manually or by using `std::swap`).

BTW: you need to initialize `max` and `min` with `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, respectively, and not the other way around.
So it needs to be

```
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
```

Otherwise, if you write `int max = INT_MAX`, then no comparison like `if(array[i][j] > max)` will ever evaluate to true, since there is no integral value greater than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: i need to know how to assign indexes in 2-D arrays

Comment: Like this: `array[i][j] = rand() % 10;     //generating randoms`

Comment: @ Tim Randall I have edited the code above , you can run and see it . In the final result I need the values of max and min to be swapped . But the array remains as it is.

Comment: @Dr.lackedu: The error is in `max/min`-initialisation; See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

The swapping is done at the end of main() using std::swap().

I broke a couple of routines into functions.  The answer would be improved by breaking out more functions so that each function performs a single task.  Still, I added a class, yet tried to stay true to your original design for printing the triangle halves. Hope you can handle some classes at this point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y, int value) : x(x), y(y), value(value) {}
    int X() { return x; }
    int Y() { return y; }
    int Value() { return value; }
    void SetValue(int valueArg) { value = valueArg; }
    void SetPoint(int xArg, int yArg, int valueArg) {
        x = xArg;
        y = yArg;
        value = valueArg;
    }

    string to_string() {
        return std::to_string(value);
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
};

void PrintArray(int **array, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int rows, columns;
    cout << "Enter rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter columns: ";
    cin >> columns;
    int **array = new int *[rows];    //generating random array
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = rand() % 10;     //generating randoms
        }
    }
    PrintArray(array, rows, columns);
    Point maxPoint = Point(0, 0, INT_MIN); // initialize max
    Point minPoint = Point(0, 0, INT_MAX);;
    cout << "For finding Max: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {            //separating the upper half
        for (int j = 0; j < columns - i; j++) {
            if (j > columns - i) {
                cout << array[i][j] << " ";
            } else {
                cout << array[i][j] << " ";
                if (array[i][j] > maxPoint.Value()) {
                    maxPoint.SetPoint(i, j, array[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "For finding Min: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {         //separating the lower half
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (j < columns - i - 1) {
                cout << "  ";
            } else {
                cout << array[i][j] << " ";
                if (array[i][j] < minPoint.Value()) {
                    minPoint.SetPoint(i, j, array[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "array before: " << endl;
    PrintArray(array, rows, columns);
    cout << "Swapping " << "maxPoint(" << maxPoint.X() << ", " << 
        maxPoint.Y() << ") with minPoint("
        << minPoint.X() << ", " << minPoint.Y() << ")" << endl;
    std::swap(
        minPoint.GetCellReference(array), 
        maxPoint.GetCellReference(array));
    PrintArray(array, rows, columns);
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in one of the comments, std::swap() is one method of performing a swap.  I have modified the example to use std:swap() at the end of main();

Comment: Prefer using `std::swap` to its trivial implementation

Comment: @Fureeish I have modified the end of main() to call std::swap().  I had never tried that on a reference to an array before.  Very nice!